# Vaadin DateField showing "null" instead of Days and Month

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a vaadin application with a `DateField`. Sometimes randomly the days and the month are displayed as `null`. The locale is set to German.
Any idea on how to prevent this?

[image]

instead of:

[image]

EDIT: I did some more testing, in the `UI.init()` method I set the locale of the session. If I remove this line it works:

```
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    getSession().setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    ....
}
```

Comment: Sorry, could not reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out I have to set the locale of the `UI` first:

```
protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
    setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    getSession().setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    ....
}
```